# Does final keyword on method parameter get compiled to bytecode?

Tags: java, bytecode

I have the following class:

```
public class Test {
  private int a;

  public Test(final int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
}
```

I tried compiling (using `javac Test.java`) with and without the `final` keyword on `a`. In both cases, when I decompile (using `javap -v -c Test.class`) I get the following bytecode (java 11, open jdk):

```
Classfile /home/sadeep/repos/podium.cubs-cnt-svc-modelruntime/src/main/java/podium/cubs/cnt/svc/modelruntime/Test.class
  Last modified Nov 3, 2021; size 261 bytes
  MD5 checksum aa55c5cbaad8a25b1ebf28a572fa72e3
  Compiled from "Test.java"
public class podium.cubs.cnt.svc.modelruntime.Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 55
  flags: (0x0021) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #3                          // podium/cubs/cnt/svc/modelruntime/Test
  super_class: #4                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 1, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #4.#13         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #3.#14         // podium/cubs/cnt/svc/modelruntime/Test.a:I
   #3 = Class              #15            // podium/cubs/cnt/svc/modelruntime/Test
   #4 = Class              #16            // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               a
   #6 = Utf8               I
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               (I)V
   #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #12 = Utf8               Test.java
  #13 = NameAndType        #7:#17         // "<init>":()V
  #14 = NameAndType        #5:#6          // a:I
  #15 = Utf8               podium/cubs/cnt/svc/modelruntime/Test
  #16 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #17 = Utf8               ()V
{
  public podium.cubs.cnt.svc.modelruntime.Test(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iload_1
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 6: 0
        line 7: 4
        line 8: 9
}
SourceFile: "Test.java"
```

Is `final` on method parameters not a jvm construct?

EDIT:

`javap -p -c -v`:

```
Classfile /home/sadeep/Test.class
  Last modified Nov 3, 2021; size 228 bytes
  MD5 checksum 2f3a79a3c91a62a2d7831651be24168b
  Compiled from "test.java"
class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 55
  flags: (0x0020) ACC_SUPER
  this_class: #3                          // Test
  super_class: #4                         // java/lang/Object
  interfaces: 0, fields: 1, methods: 1, attributes: 1
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #4.#13         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Fieldref           #3.#14         // Test.a:I
   #3 = Class              #15            // Test
   #4 = Class              #16            // java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               a
   #6 = Utf8               I
   #7 = Utf8               <init>
   #8 = Utf8               (I)V
   #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #11 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #12 = Utf8               test.java
  #13 = NameAndType        #7:#17         // "<init>":()V
  #14 = NameAndType        #5:#6          // a:I
  #15 = Utf8               Test
  #16 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #17 = Utf8               ()V
{
  private final int a;
    descriptor: I
    flags: (0x0012) ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_FINAL

  public Test(int);
    descriptor: (I)V
    flags: (0x0001) ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: iload_1
         6: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
         9: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
        line 4: 4
        line 5: 9
}
SourceFile: "test.java"
```

Looks like even with -p, the final indicator is only set for the field.

Comment: Add `-p` to your `javap` options.

Comment: Not sure why the JVM would need to know if a method parameter is final.  The compiler has built you a method doesn't modify that parameter; and if you're able to change that method so that it DOES modify the parameter, then you could also change it to remove whatever tells the JVM that the parameter is final.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem makes sense. I was wondering if it takes part in jit like the fields.

Comment: It's all in the compiler. The JVM does not need to know whether the variable, method or class is final. The compiler prevents the programmer from doing certain things and may even use the fact that it's final to optimize the bytecodes.

Comment: @llswdon the JIT knows whether there are actual assignments to a variable or not, it doesn’t need a `final` flag to detect this. In fact, if there are assignments, it will transform the code into the [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) to have final-like variables to work with…

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem in fact, having a `final` parameter but writes to the associated local variable at the bytecode level would not be wrong. It could simply mean that the parameter is unused past this point and the compiler reused its storage for a different variable. Similar to `{ int i = 1; i = 2; }` and `{ final int i = 1; }{ final int i = 2; }` producing exactly the same bytecode. In principle, even `this` can be reused for a different purpose on the bytecode level, if this reference is not used afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: You don’t need that information in the bytecode**

The `final` keyword on a parameter means that you cannot assign a value to that parameter inside your method or constructor. It’s the compiler’s job to check that you are not doing this (and the compiler will issue an error message if you do). Once the compiler has done its job, we can be assured that the parameter indeed keeps its initial value throughout. There is no need to have the information in the bytecode that the parameter is declared `final`. Which is why the information is not there.

From a comment by Link182:

> Then how do we know the parameter is final in a compiled library?

You don’t. You don’t need to. What would you use that information for? It’s only relevant for the implementor of the method.

Comment: Then how do we know the parameter is final in a compiled library?

Comment: @Link182 You don’t. You don’t need to. What would you use that information for? It’s only relevant for the implementor of the method.

Comment: @OleV.V. It becomes available to reflection when using the `-parameters` option. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters()

Answer (score 2):

The MethodParameters attribute is used to indicate that parameters are final. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.24

In order for javac to add this attribute, you need to pass the `-parameters` option.

Comment: I added an edit. Doesn't see a difference to the ctor parameter.

Comment: @llswdon It is added at the bottom as a `MethodParameters:` entry, which lists the parameters names and flag (which include the `final` flag).

Comment: @llswdon you need to pass `-parameters` to javac, and then run javap again.

Answer (score 0):

Though the `final` keyword may not be compiled into the bytecode, it does enable major compiler optimizations. Borrowing from Strmecki (2021), consider the two versions of a method that concatenates 2 strings:

**Version 1 Using the `final` keyword**

```java
public static String concatFinalStrings() {
    final String x = "x";
    final String y = "y";
    return x + y;
}
```

**Version 2 without the `final` keyword**

```java
public static String concatNonFinalStrings() {
    String x = "x";
    String y = "y";
    return x + y;
}
```

Strmecki got the following benchmark results:

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
BenchmarkRunner.concatFinalStrings     avgt  200  2,976 ± 0,035  ns/op
BenchmarkRunner.concatNonFinalStrings  avgt  200  7,375 ± 0,119  ns/op
```

**Version 1 is compiled to yield this bytecode**

```
LDC "xy"
ARETURN
```

**Version 2 is compiled to yield this bytecode**

```
NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
DUP
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init> ()V
ALOAD 0
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
ALOAD 1
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString ()Ljava/lang/String;
ARETURN
```

Clearly, the compiler is able to find very efficient optimizations when you tell it "this variable will NOT change."

---

Strmecki, D. (2021). The Java final Keyword – Impact on Performance. Baeldung.Com. https://www.baeldung.com/java-final-performance